# Applying Unity quaternions / Euler Angle rotation to vectors for data analysis sanity/logic check

Tags: r, unity-game-engine, quaternions, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

**Backstory:**
I'm currently writing a thesis where I am looking at the difference of movements in reality and VR. To do this I've attached a Vive Tracker to the people and tracked their head location and orientation (both in quaternions and Euler angles(EA)).

I would like to visualise the movement trajectories using the angles around the X and Y axis.
(Z is aimed away from the looking direction, Y is up and X is sideways).

**My current approach:**

I've had users look at a certain spot for some time to calibrate, this vector should be approximately along the negative Z axis.

Due to the way the tracker was fixed to the person it is pitching downwards. How much depends on the person. I transform the quaternions & EA to a rotation matrix for each calibration timestep and take the average over all calibration timesteps, and apply this to the three normal vectors along the three axis. I get three new vectors which define the orientation of the tracker. To account for the pitch of the tracker I calculate the vector of where the plane spanned by the X and Z coordinate system vectors and the plane spanned by the trackers own Z and Y vectors. This is the pointing vector. (There are some bugs/features where the tracker randomly switches the coordinate system, so I'm only 90% sure the coordinate system is right, the results do seem close enough.)
Applying the inverse calibration rotation matrix should yield a vector for me to apply future rotations which should then yield vectors pointing in the direction the person was pointing their head at.

So far so good, I've done this using both quaternions and the EA, which are close enough in results, yet still worringly different... Also, for one the z vector is somehow inversed. I guess one mistake somewhere with a minus or rotation convention somewhere that I can not find, but that's not the main issue.

This is the code I used for calibration:

Using Quaternions:

```
#Calibration RB

c0 <- 1;
calw <- 0;
calx <- 0;
caly <- 0;
calz <- 0;

C <- c(c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0));

while (dataRB$Phase[c0] == "Calibration") {
  calw <- dataRB$wquat[c0]# + calw;
  calx <- dataRB$xquat[c0]# + calx;
  caly <- dataRB$yquat[c0]# + caly;
  calz <- dataRB$zquat[c0]# + calz;
  c0 <- c0+1;

# q0 <- calw#/(c0-1);
# q1 <- calx#/(c0-1);
# q2 <- caly#/(c0-1);
# q3 <- calz#/(c0-1);

q0 <- calw#/(c0-1);
q1 <- -calx#/(c0-1);
q2 <- -calz#/(c0-1);
q3 <- -caly#/(c0-1);

# First row of the rotation matrix
r00 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q1 * q1) - 1;
r01 <- 2 * (q1 * q2 - q0 * q3);
r02 <- 2 * (q1 * q3 + q0 * q2);

# Second row of the rotation matrix
r10 <- 2 * (q1 * q2 + q0 * q3);
r11 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q2 * q2) - 1;
r12 <- 2 * (q2 * q3 - q0 * q1);

# Third row of the rotation matrix
r20 <- 2 * (q1 * q3 - q0 * q2);
r21 <- 2 * (q2 * q3 + q0 * q1);
r22 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q3 * q3) - 1;

# 3x3 rotation matrix
C <- C + c(c(r00, r01, r02),c(r10, r11, r12),c(r20, r21, r22));
}
C <- C/(c0-1);
calquat <- matrix(C,nrow=3,ncol=3);
# print(c0);
# print("calquat");
# print(calquat);
calquatinv <- inv(calquat);

  X_n <- c(1,0,0);
  Y_n <- c(0,1,0);
  Z_n <- c(0,0,1);

  Px <- c(calquat[1,1]*X_n[1]+calquat[1,2]*X_n[2]+calquat[1,3]*X_n[3],calquat[2,1]*X_n[1]+calquat[2,2]*X_n[2]+calquat[2,3]*X_n[3],calquat[3,1]*X_n[1]+calquat[3,2]*X_n[2]+calquat[3,3]*X_n[3]);
  Py <- c(calquat[1,1]*Y_n[1]+calquat[1,2]*Y_n[2]+calquat[1,3]*Y_n[3],calquat[2,1]*Y_n[1]+calquat[2,2]*Y_n[2]+calquat[2,3]*Y_n[3],calquat[3,1]*Y_n[1]+calquat[3,2]*Y_n[2]+calquat[3,3]*Y_n[3]);
  Pz <- c(calquat[1,1]*Z_n[1]+calquat[1,2]*Z_n[2]+calquat[1,3]*Z_n[3],calquat[2,1]*Z_n[1]+calquat[2,2]*Z_n[2]+calquat[2,3]*Z_n[3],calquat[3,1]*Z_n[1]+calquat[3,2]*Z_n[2]+calquat[3,3]*Z_n[3]);


 N <- c((Y_n[2]*Px[3]) - (Y_n[3]*Px[2]), (Y_n[3]*Px[1]) - (Y_n[1]*Px[3]), (Y_n[1]*Px[2]) - (Y_n[2]*Px[1]))
 #N <- c(0,0,1)

  Pn <- c(calquatinv[1,1]*N[1]+calquatinv[1,2]*N[2]+calquatinv[1,3]*N[3],calquatinv[2,1]*N[1]+calquatinv[2,2]*N[2]+calquatinv[2,3]*N[3],calquatinv[3,1]*N[1]+calquatinv[3,2]*N[2]+calquatinv[3,3]*N[3]);

  
basismatrix1 <- matrix(c(c((Y_n[2]*N[3]) - (Y_n[3]*N[2]), (Y_n[3]*N[1]) - (Y_n[1]*N[3]), (Y_n[1]*N[2]) - (Y_n[2]*N[1])),c(0,1,0),c(N[1],N[2],N[3])),nrow=3,ncol=3);

basismatrix1 <- t(basismatrix1)
```

Using EA:

```
 xrot <- 0
  yrot <- 0
  zrot <- 0
  
  R <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=3)
  
  c0 <- 1

while (dataRB$Phase[c0] == "Calibration") {
  xrot <- dataRB$xrot[c0]/180*pi-pi + xrot;
  yrot <- dataRB$yrot[c0]/180*pi-pi + yrot;
  zrot <- dataRB$zrot[c0]/180*pi-pi + zrot;
  c0 <- c0+1;
}
  a <- xrot/(c0-1)
  b <- yrot/(c0-1)
  c <- zrot/(c0-1)

  
  # a <- 0
  # b <- 0
  # c <- 0
  
  Rx <- matrix(c(c(1,0,0),c(0,cos(a),-sin(a)),c(0,sin(a),cos(a))),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    
  Ry <- matrix(c(c(cos(b),0,sin(b)),c(0,1,0),c(-sin(b),0,cos(b))),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    
  Rz <- matrix(c(c(cos(c),-sin(c),0),c(sin(c),cos(c),0),c(0,0,1)),nrow=3,ncol=3)
  
  R <- Ry%*%Rx%*%Rz# + R;
  
#}
  
  #R <- R/(c0-1)
  
  Rinv <- inv(R)

  X_n <- c(1,0,0);
  Y_n <- c(0,1,0);
  Z_n <- c(0,0,1);

  Px <- c(R[1,1]*X_n[1]+R[1,2]*X_n[2]+R[1,3]*X_n[3],R[2,1]*X_n[1]+R[2,2]*X_n[2]+R[2,3]*X_n[3],R[3,1]*X_n[1]+R[3,2]*X_n[2]+R[3,3]*X_n[3]);
  Py <- c(R[1,1]*Y_n[1]+R[1,2]*Y_n[2]+R[1,3]*Y_n[3],R[2,1]*Y_n[1]+R[2,2]*Y_n[2]+R[2,3]*Y_n[3],R[3,1]*Y_n[1]+R[3,2]*Y_n[2]+R[3,3]*Y_n[3]);
  Pz <- c(R[1,1]*Z_n[1]+R[1,2]*Z_n[2]+R[1,3]*Z_n[3],R[2,1]*Z_n[1]+R[2,2]*Z_n[2]+R[2,3]*Z_n[3],R[3,1]*Z_n[1]+R[3,2]*Z_n[2]+R[3,3]*Z_n[3]);


 N <- c((Y_n[2]*Px[3]) - (Y_n[3]*Px[2]), (Y_n[3]*Px[1]) - (Y_n[1]*Px[3]), (Y_n[1]*Px[2]) - (Y_n[2]*Px[1]))
 #N <- c(0,0,1)

  Pn <- c(Rinv[1,1]*N[1]+Rinv[1,2]*N[2]+Rinv[1,3]*N[3],Rinv[2,1]*N[1]+Rinv[2,2]*N[2]+Rinv[2,3]*N[3],Rinv[3,1]*N[1]+Rinv[3,2]*N[2]+Rinv[3,3]*N[3]);
  
  basismatrix2 <- matrix(c(c((Y_n[2]*N[3]) - (Y_n[3]*N[2]), (Y_n[3]*N[1]) - (Y_n[1]*N[3]), (Y_n[1]*N[2]) - (Y_n[2]*N[1])),c(0,1,0),c(N[1],N[2],N[3])),nrow=3,ncol=3);
  
  basismatrix2 <- t(basismatrix2)
```

To calculate my two vectors I calculate the pitch between the pointing vector and its projection on the Z-X plane. This yields the pitch. If the Y component of the pointer is negative, I then make the angle negative. For the yaw (rotation around the Y axis) I simply calcualte the angle between the calibrated pointer (which lies in the X-Z plane) and the pointer vector projected on the X-Z plane. Again, if X component of the pointer is smaller than x component of the calibration pointer, I make the angle negative.

Using Quaternions:

```
c1 <- 1

while (c1 < nrow(dataRB)+1) {


  # q0 <- dataRB$wquat[c1];
  # q1 <- dataRB$xquat[c1];
  # q2 <- dataRB$yquat[c1];
  # q3 <- dataRB$zquat[c1];

q0 <- dataRB$wquat[c1];
q1 <- -dataRB$xquat[c1];
q2 <- -dataRB$zquat[c1];
q3 <- -dataRB$yquat[c1];


  # First row of the rotation matrix
  r00 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q1 * q1) - 1;
  r01 <- 2 * (q1 * q2 - q0 * q3);
  r02 <- 2 * (q1 * q3 + q0 * q2);

  # Second row of the rotation matrix
  r10 <- 2 * (q1 * q2 + q0 * q3);
  r11 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q2 * q2) - 1;
  r12 <- 2 * (q2 * q3 - q0 * q1);

  # Third row of the rotation matrix
  r20 <- 2 * (q1 * q3 - q0 * q2);
  r21 <- 2 * (q2 * q3 + q0 * q1);
  r22 <- 2 * (q0 * q0 + q3 * q3) - 1;

  # 3x3 rotation matrix
  C <- c(c(r00, r01, r02),c(r10, r11, r12),c(r20, r21, r22));
  rot_Matrix = matrix(C,nrow=3,ncol=3);

  Pnt <- c(rot_Matrix[1,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[1,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[1,3]*Pn[3],rot_Matrix[2,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[2,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[2,3]*Pn[3],rot_Matrix[3,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[3,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[3,3]*Pn[3]);
  
  yaw <- -(acos((Pnt[1]*N[1]+0+Pnt[3]*N[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(N[1]*N[1]+N[3]*N[3]))))/pi*180;
  pitch <- (acos((Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[2]*Pnt[2]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3]))))/pi*180;
  #pitch2 <- (atan(Pnt[2]/sqrt(Pnt[1]^2+Pnt[3]^2)))/pi*180;
  #angle <- (acos((Pnt[1]*N[1]+Pnt[2]*N[2]+Pnt[3]*N[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[2]*Pnt[2]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(N[1]*N[1]*N[2]*N[2]+N[3]*N[3]))))/pi*180;
  
  if(Pnt[2] < 0){
    pitch <- -pitch
  }
  if(Pnt[1] < N[1]){
    yaw <- -yaw
  }
  
  dataRB$pitch[c1] = round(pitch,7)
  dataRB$yaw[c1] = round(yaw,7)
  #dataRB$angle[c1] = round(angle,7)
  
  dataRB$Px[c1] = round(Pnt[1],7)
  dataRB$Py[c1] = round(Pnt[2],7)
  dataRB$Pz[c1] = round(Pnt[3],7)
  
  #dataRB$pitch2[c1] = round(pitch2,7)
  
  
  if(c1 > 2){

  P_pre <- c(dataRB$Px[c1-2],dataRB$Py[c1-2],dataRB$Pz[c1-2]);
  P_current <- c(dataRB$Px[c1-1],dataRB$Py[c1-1],dataRB$Pz[c1-1]);
  P_post <- c(dataRB$Px[c1],dataRB$Py[c1],dataRB$Pz[c1]);

  #print(P_pre);
  #print(P_current);
  #print(P_post);

  T_pre <- c(dataRB$Time[c1-2]);
  T_current <- c(dataRB$Time[c1-1]);
  T_post <- c(dataRB$Time[c1]);

  #print(T_pre);
  #print(T_current);
  #print(T_post);


  suppressWarnings(preangle <- acos( sum(P_pre*P_current) / ( sqrt(sum(P_pre * P_pre)) * sqrt(sum(P_current * P_current)))))

  suppressWarnings(postangle <- acos(sum(P_pre*P_post) / ( sqrt(sum(P_current * P_current)) * sqrt(sum(P_post * P_post)))))

  #print(preangle);
  #print(postangle);

  preangle <- preangle/pi*180;
  postangle <- postangle/pi*180;

  #dataRB$angle[c1-1] <- preangle;

  #print("angles");
  #print(preangle);
  #print(postangle);

  #print("timesteps");
  #print(T_current-T_pre);
  #print(T_post-T_current);

  V <- (preangle/(T_current-T_pre)+postangle/(T_post-T_current))/2;

  dataRB$V[c1-1] <- round(V,7);

  #print("V");
  #print(dataRB$V[c1-1]);

  #dataRB$preangle[c1-1] <- preangle;
  #dataRB$postangle[c1-1] <- postangle;
  #dataRB$timestep_pre[c1-1] <- (T_current-T_pre);
  #dataRB$timestep_post[c1-1] <- (T_post-T_current);
  
  if(c1 > 3){
    dataRB$Va[c1-2] <- round(((dataRB$V[c1-2]-dataRB$V[c1-3])/(dataRB$Time[c1-2]-dataRB$Time[c1-3])+(dataRB$V[c1-1]-dataRB$V[c1-2])/(dataRB$Time[c1-1]-dataRB$Time[c1-2]))/2,7);
  }

  # if(is.nan(preangle)){
  #   c1 <- c1-1;
  #   dataRB <- dataRB[-c(c1), ]
  # }
  # 
  # if(is.nan(postangle)){
  #   c1 <- c1-1;
  #   dataRB <- dataRB[-c(c1), ]
  # }
  }
  
  
c1 <- c1 + 1;

}
```

Using EA:

```
c1 <- 1

while (c1 < nrow(dataRB)+1) {
  
  
  xrot <- dataRB$xrot[c1]/180*pi# + xrot;
  yrot <- dataRB$yrot[c1]/180*pi# + yrot;
  zrot <- dataRB$zrot[c1]/180*pi# + zrot;

  a <- xrot-pi#/(c0-1)
  b <- yrot-pi#/(c0-1)
  c <- zrot-pi#/(c0-1)
  
  
  Rx <- matrix(c(c(1,0,0),c(0,cos(a),-sin(a)),c(0,sin(a),cos(a))),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    
  Ry <- matrix(c(c(cos(b),0,sin(b)),c(0,1,0),c(-sin(b),0,cos(b))),nrow=3,ncol=3)
    
  Rz <- matrix(c(c(cos(c),-sin(c),0),c(sin(c),cos(c),0),c(0,0,1)),nrow=3,ncol=3)
  
  R <- Ry%*%Rx%*%Rz;
  
  #R <- matrix(c(c()))
  
  #EA <- c(a,b,c)
  
  #R2 <- EA2DCM(EA,"yxz")
 
  rot_Matrix = R;

Pnt <- c(rot_Matrix[1,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[1,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[1,3]*Pn[3],rot_Matrix[2,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[2,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[2,3]*Pn[3],rot_Matrix[3,1]*Pn[1]+rot_Matrix[3,2]*Pn[2]+rot_Matrix[3,3]*Pn[3]);
  
  yaw <- (acos((Pnt[1]*N[1]+0+Pnt[3]*N[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(N[1]*N[1]+N[3]*N[3]))))/pi*180;
  pitch <- (acos((Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[2]*Pnt[2]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3]))))/pi*180;
  #pitch2 <- (atan(Pnt[2]/sqrt(Pnt[1]^2+Pnt[3]^2)))/pi*180;
  
  #angle <- (acos((Pnt[1]*N[1]+Pnt[2]*N[2]+Pnt[3]*N[3])/(sqrt(Pnt[1]*Pnt[1]+Pnt[2]*Pnt[2]+Pnt[3]*Pnt[3])*sqrt(N[1]*N[1]*N[2]*N[2]+N[3]*N[3]))))/pi*180;
  
  if(Pnt[2] < 0){
    pitch <- -pitch
  }
  
  if(Pnt[1] < 0){
    yaw <- -yaw
  }
  
  dataRB$pitch2[c1] = round(pitch,7)
  dataRB$yaw2[c1] = round(yaw,7)
  #dataRB$angle2[c1] = round(angle,7)
  
  dataRB$P2x[c1] = round(Pnt[1],7)
  dataRB$P2y[c1] = round(Pnt[2],7)
  dataRB$P2z[c1] = round(Pnt[3],7)
  
  
  if(c1 > 2){

  P_pre <- c(dataRB$P2x[c1-2],dataRB$P2y[c1-2],dataRB$P2z[c1-2]);
  P_current <- c(dataRB$P2x[c1-1],dataRB$P2y[c1-1],dataRB$P2z[c1-1]);
  P_post <- c(dataRB$P2x[c1],dataRB$P2y[c1],dataRB$P2z[c1]);

  #print(P_pre);
  #print(P_current);
  #print(P_post);

  T_pre <- c(dataRB$Time[c1-2]);
  T_current <- c(dataRB$Time[c1-1]);
  T_post <- c(dataRB$Time[c1]);

  #print(T_pre);
  #print(T_current);
  #print(T_post);


  suppressWarnings(preangle <- acos( sum(P_pre*P_current) / ( sqrt(sum(P_pre * P_pre)) * sqrt(sum(P_current * P_current)))))

  suppressWarnings(postangle <- acos(sum(P_pre*P_post) / ( sqrt(sum(P_current * P_current)) * sqrt(sum(P_post * P_post)))))

  #print(preangle);
  #print(postangle);

  preangle <- preangle/pi*180;
  postangle <- postangle/pi*180;

  #dataRB$angle[c1-1] <- preangle;

  #print("angles");
  #print(preangle);
  #print(postangle);

  #print("timesteps");
  #print(T_current-T_pre);
  #print(T_post-T_current);

  V <- (preangle/(T_current-T_pre)+postangle/(T_post-T_current))/2;

  dataRB$V2[c1-1] <- round(V,7);

  #print("V");
  #print(dataRB$V[c1-1]);

  #dataRB$preangle[c1-1] <- preangle;
  #dataRB$postangle[c1-1] <- postangle;
  #dataRB$timestep_pre[c1-1] <- (T_current-T_pre);
  #dataRB$timestep_post[c1-1] <- (T_post-T_current);

  if(c1 > 3){
    dataRB$V2a[c1-2] <- round(((dataRB$V2[c1-2]-dataRB$V2[c1-3])/(dataRB$Time[c1-2]-dataRB$Time[c1-3])+(dataRB$V2[c1-1]-dataRB$V2[c1-2])/(dataRB$Time[c1-1]-dataRB$Time[c1-2]))/2,7);
  }

  # if(is.nan(preangle)){
  #   c1 <- c1-1;
  #   dataRB <- dataRB[-c(c1), ]
  # }
  # 
  # if(is.nan(postangle)){
  #   c1 <- c1-1;
  #   dataRB <- dataRB[-c(c1), ]
  # }
  }
  
  
c1 <- c1 + 1;
   
}
```

I've been using RStudio to do this (and have already surpassed the labs monthly computing time working on this). Now my results make somewhat sense for all the rotations below 45 degrees, however, for what should be approximately a 90 degree rotation I do get a pitch of -40 degrees. It seems possible, but unrealistic. I am not sure if this was the case. The user study had over 30 participants, I can't recall all their movements.

If anybody would be so kind to logic check my logic and if somebody is motivated to further dive in to this issue and maybe help me out by pointing out potential errors in my code, please feel free.
The github repository is open and can be found here: https://github.com/NicK4rT/Unity-Projects/tree/main/Recordings
It includes all the datasets used and the analysis rstudio code in the Recordings folder. (Analysis.qmd is the code).

I've also attached the complete code used to import, tidy and transform the first 27 data sets. It is three times the same code, but for the three different types of data sets.

Link to data set I used for testing before running the code: https://github.com/NicK4rT/Unity-Projects/blob/main/Recordings/Sorting/US1RB.csv
Resulting data set after running the code: https://github.com/NicK4rT/Unity-Projects/blob/main/Recordings/Clean/US1RB.csv

Complete analysis code: https://github.com/NicK4rT/Unity-Projects/blob/main/Recordings/Analysis.qmd (too long to include in this post)

**Conclusion:**

To answer questions: Yes my code is bad and messy, I'm sorry about that. I should feel bad and I do feel bad.
Furthermore, why didn't I just raycast and calculate the voctor directly in unity? Because I'm stupid and didn't think it was needed and sadly I didn't have the time to properly test everything as I had to also implement eye tracking before the study. I just didn't know better and now I'm in this analysis mess with a deadline approaching fast. Lessons learned.

Any help is appreciated. I can't tell what makes sense anymore.

Comment: This is more of a statistical question rather than a programming question, so maybe it should go to Cross Validated, though I think it's too long.  I think you should shorten it to make it very clear what you are asking if you want a helpful answer.

Comment: BTW, the `orientlib` package in R does similar calculations to what you're doing; you could use it to validate your formulas (or to replace them).

Comment: And perhaps [tsmp-motif rule discovery](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/RuleDiscovery_Extended_002.pdf), pg 9, I'd be interested in taking a look at your eye tracking data if it is in the same repository.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for your comments. I have tested several such packages and at least for my quaternion transformation I seem to get the same results, same for the EAs. I am accounting for handedness in my quaternion transformation, however, trying to get the euler angles I recorded from unity from the quaternions has proven impossible. I have tried every rotation matrix order for both LHS and RHS, yet I never got those same EAs... Not quite sure what the issue was. I am still confident in that i am doing something right, the data does seem to make somewhat sense, but only somewhat...

Comment: @Chris Data for eye tracking (specifically eye gaze vector and eye gaze origin and some more like focus distance and focused object) is in the same dataset. Keep in mind these datasets are the raw thing and I didn't write any documentation explaining the datasets, but feel free to have a look at the eye tracking data, my repo is public after all. Let me know if you have questions. For your info: Eye gaze was recorded using the HTC Vive Pro Eye HMD.

Comment: And could you specify, what LR, RB, VR by user in /Clean/... signify.

Comment: Your comment "I never got those same EAs" sounds like exactly the right sort of question for SO.  Put together a self-contained minimal example showing what you tried and what values you think should match but don't match, and you'll probably get useful help.  Right now your question is just too open-ended.

Comment: @user2554330 Fair enough. I think I will probably do that in this case.

Comment: @Chris RB, LR and VR are the three different test conditions. RB = Reality, LR = Limited Reality (FoV restricted, same FoV as VR), VR = Virtual Reality. I've had them look at things 9 cards per wall, named 1-9 , on three different walls (B front, A left, C right. User was in the middle. The looking orders are a bit different depending on the conditions and orders. I will gladly tell you more once I finally finish this project.